# Switch rows in data.table to create uniform variable

Tags: r, loops, optimization, data.table

I want to write a script to help me distribute piglets over pens while maintaining a similar average weight between pens by switching animals (rows) between pens to achieve this, but only switching piglets which have the same mother (i.e. the same sowid). So far I got the following script which leads to some improvement but I suspect it is not the optimal algorithm to achieve this goal. Any better ideas?

```
    test <- data.table(sowid=c(12,23,25,45,65,12,58,85,96,85,45,23),pen=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),pigletid=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),weight=c(6.5,5.9,6.2,5.8,7.5,7.2,7.8,6.9,9.5,10.2,9.8,6.4))

count <- 0
switch <- c(0,0)
cutoff <- 0.1

while(count == 0){
  meanPP <- test [,mean(weight),.(pen)]
  names(meanPP) <- c("pen","Mean")
  meanPP <- meanPP[order(Mean)]

  if (max(meanPP$Mean) - min(meanPP$Mean) <= cutoff){
    test <- test[order(pen)]
    count <- count + 1
  }else{
    count2 <- 0
    i <- 0
    while (count2 == 0 & i <= nrow(meanPP)){
      maxH <- meanPP$pen[nrow(meanPP)-i] 
      for (j in (nrow(test)/nrow(meanPP)):1){
        maxA <- test[pen==maxH]
        maxA <- maxA[order(weight)]$pigletid[j]
        if ((test$sowid[which(test$pigletid == maxA)] %in% test$sowid[-which(test$pigletid == maxA)]) && test[sowid == test$sowid[which(test$pigletid == maxA)],min(weight)] < test[pigletid == maxA,weight]){
          maxA <- which(test$pigletid == maxA)
          count2 <- count2 +1
          break
        }
      }
      i <- i + 1
    }

    for (i in 1:nrow(meanPP)) {
      minH <- meanPP$pen[i]
      minA <- test[pen==minH]
      if (test$sowid[maxA] %in% minA$sowid && minA[sowid==test$sowid[maxA]]$weight < test$weight[maxA]){
        minA <- minA[sowid==test$sowid[maxA]]
        minA <- minA[sowid==test$sowid[maxA]]$pigletid
        minA <- which(test$pigletid == minA)
        break
      }
    }

    if (minA == switch[2] & maxA == switch[1]){
      count <- count +1
    }

    switch <- c(minA,maxA)

    tempRow <- test$pen[maxA]
    test$pen[maxA] <- test$pen[minA]
    test$pen[minA] <- tempRow

    test <- test[order(pen)]
  }
}
```

In response to Anurag N. Sharma, I would like output something like this:

```
> test
    sowid pen pigletid weight
 1:    25   1        3    6.2
 2:    45   1       11    9.8
 3:    23   1       12    6.4
 4:    12   1        6    7.2
 5:    12   2        1    6.5
 6:    65   2        5    7.5
 7:    58   2        7    7.8
 8:    85   2        8    6.9
 9:    85   3       10   10.2
10:    23   3        2    5.9
11:    45   3        4    5.8
12:    96   3        9    9.5
```

Where I can get the mean weight of each pen within as close to 0.1 difference as possible to the other pens.

Comment: Can you add an expected output to compare with the input?

Comment: Can you elaborate on only switching pigs with the same mother? Do you only want to swap pigs of the same mother between pens, i.e. if I have 4 piglets across 2 pens, I can only swap 2 between pens if they are the same mother (assuming this is to minimize the cage/genetic effects)

Comment: @NoThatKindODr that's exactly what I mean

Comment: i think this is more of a optimization problem. You might want to update the tags and also clarify on *switching piglets which have the same mother*

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks for the suggestion, I updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying a (stochastic) Local Search to solve
the problem.  In essence, you make random switches to
your allocation of piglets and keep those that decrease
the differences in weights.

Alternative representations are possible, but one
possibility is this: A candidate solution is a vector
that maps the piglets to pens; so your column `pen`
would be an initial solution.  The *k*-th element of
such a solution gives the pen in which piglet *k* goes.

Let's map this initial solution into a solution
quality, i.e. write an objective function `OF`.

```
df <- data.frame(sowid = c(12,23,25,45,65,12,58,85,96,85,45,23),
                 pen   = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                 pigletid = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
                 weight   = c(6.5,5.9,6.2,5.8,7.5,7.2,7.8,6.9,9.5,10.2,9.8,6.4))

x <- df$pen
OF <- function(x, df, ...)
    sd(tapply(df$weight, x, mean))
OF(x, df)
## [1] 1.44157
```

Note that I used a standard data.frame to represent
your data. `OF` computes the standard deviation of
average weights, but you could try other specifications
as well.

Now for the random sampling: randomly select one sow
*s* with more than one piglet; random select two
piglets that belong to *s*; exchange their positions.
Note that I precompute `sowids` so that I do not end up
with sows with only a single piglet.

```
sowids <- as.numeric(names(table(df$sowid)[table(df$sowid) > 1]))

nb <- function(x, df, sowids) {
    s <- sowids[sample(length(sowids), 1)]
    ij <- sample(which(df$sowid == s))[1:2]
    x[ij] <- x[rev(ij)]
    x    
}
```

`nb` (which stands for neighbour) implements this sampling. The function takes a candidate
solution `x`and returns a slightly changed solution.

```
x
## [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
nb(x, df, sowids)
## [1] 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 3 3 3 3
nb(nb(x, df, sowids), df, sowids)
## [1] 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 3 3 3 3
```

Now we can run the Local Search.  I use the
implementation in package [`NMOF`](https://github.com/enricoschumann/NMOF) (of which I am the 
maintainer).

```
library("NMOF")
sol.ls <- LSopt(OF, list(x0 = df$pen,
                         neighbour = nb,
                         nI = 1000),
                df = df, sowids = sowids)
## Local Search.
## Initial solution:  1.44157 
## Best solution overall: 0.3307189
```

We can compare the final solution with the initial one:
average weights by pen.

```
tapply(df$weight, df$pen, mean)
##     1     2     3 
## 6.100 7.350 8.975 
tapply(df$weight, sol.ls$xbest, mean)
##     1     2     3 
## 7.225 7.350 7.850
```

And a check: did we keep the correct sowids?

```
sort(df$sowid[test$pen == 1])
sort(df$sowid[which(sol.ls$xbest == 1)])

sort(df$sowid[test$pen == 2])
sort(df$sowid[which(sol.ls$xbest == 2)])

sort(df$sowid[test$pen == 3])
sort(df$sowid[which(sol.ls$xbest == 3)])
```